# What to do in this error in flutter while implementing firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Because firebase_auth >=3.2.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^3.2.0 which depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.2.0 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.2.0 is incompatible with http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0.
So, because bit_fly depends on both http ^0.12.0+2 and firebase_auth ^3.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because bit_fly depends on both http ^0.12.0+2 and firebase_auth ^3.2.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to import some package whose version doesn't match your flutter or dart's version.
What is your current flutter and dart version ??

Comment: Please dont post questions in answers - its not a good place for a dialog and can create a confusing / hard to understand / long-winded answers. Questions and comments should be posted as a comment to the question itself. Once you have an answer from the OP, include that data point as part of your answer.

Comment: the version is 2.1.0 <3.0.0